# String exceeding ajax POST length limit

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I'm trying to send an array from my jsp to my Servlet via ajax POST request. My array has a few objects with many fields. If I try to send and array with 11 objects - using JSON.stringify - it works OK (the array is received on server-side), but the problem happens when I try to send an array with 12+ objects. The error is: `400 Bad Request` and looking with Google Chrome Debugger, I can find this error: `fluxos:(unable to decode value)` where `fluxos` is the name of my array.

**RELEVANTE PART OF CODE:**

```
for(var i=0; i<numberOfConnections; i++) {
    fluxo = criaEstruturaFluxo(i);
    fluxos.push(fluxo);
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: 'Servlet?fluxos='+JSON.stringify(fluxos),
            success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
    }
});

...
function criaEstruturaFluxo(i) {
    ...
    ...
    var fluxo = {
      xOrigem: xOrigem, 
      yOrigem: yOrigem,
      xDestino: xDestino,
      yDestino: yDestino,
      codWorkflow: codWorkflow,
      acaoAvanco: acaoAvanco,
      codAtividadeOrigem: codAtividadeOrigem[1],
      codAtividadeDestino: codAtividadeDestino[1],
      numero: numero,
      nomeAtividadeOrigem: nomeAtividadeOrigem,
      nomeAtividadeDestino: nomeAtividadeDestino,
      codConexao: codConexao,
      tipoOrigem: tipoOrigem,
      tipoDestino: tipoDestino,
      xFluxoOrigem: xFluxoOrigem,
      yFluxoOrigem: yFluxoOrigem,
      xFluxoDestino: xFluxoDestino,
      yFluxoDestino: yFluxoDestino,
      deletarArquivo: deletarArquivo,
      ultimaConexao: ultimaConexao,
      caminhoArquivo: caminhoArquivo,
      xTela: xTela,
      yTela: yTela
    };

    return fluxo;
}
```

My encoded array has 8000+ characters length and because of that, I think it's exceeding the max length a POST request can handle... Is that possible or might be something on the code that I'm sending to my Servlet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agree with Andres & Luiggi. Here's what your modified code would look like:

```
$.ajax({
url: "Servlet",
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
data: JSON.stringify({ "fluxos": fluxos }),
success: function(data) {
    alert("success");
}
```

});

Answer (score 6):

Your url is very long. In theory that shouldn't cause any problems, but there's a practical limit that depends on the server and proxies that you use. Send the data on the body of the request and not on the url.

Comment: I would add to this answer that there's no use in sending a POST request if you're going to user query string parameters in the URL...

Comment: I agree 100 per cent.